# Highlight a table row if radio button has not been checked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, radio-button

**Problem:**

I have one table per tab (5 tabs in total) where each consists of three rows (one table header and two table data).

I wish to execute a JS script that scans only table rows that has the attribute `id` and then checks the radio buttons inside this row. If none has been selected then the table row should change color by adding a class to it.

Minimal (Working) Example:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-borderless" id="survey">
    <thead class="text-center">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col">1</th>
          <th scope="col">2</th>
          <th scope="col">3</th>
          <th scope="col">4</th>
          <th scope="col">5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="1">
        <td scope="row">Question 1</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="1" id="1" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="1" id="1" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="1" id="1" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="1" id="1" value="4"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="1" id="1" value="5"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="2">
        <td scope="row">Question 2</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="2" id="2" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="2" id="2" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="2" id="2" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="2" id="2" value="4"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="2" id="2" value="5"></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

The function is called upon by a button in HTML when a user attempts to switch a tab.

```
validateForm() {
    var valid = true;
    var rows = Nodes.tab[this.currentTab].querySelectorAll('tr[id]');

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

        var inputs = rows[i].querySelectorAll("input");

        for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {

          // Add class to table row?

        }
    }

    // If valid then mark step with green color
    if (valid) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("step")[this.currentTab].classList.add("finish");
    }
    // Return the valid status
    return valid; 
}
```

**Desired output:**

If a user does not check at least one radio button of a button group then add the CSS class "error" to that table row.

Comment: if you mark any of the radios in each group as `required` in HTML and attach them to a `form` element, that `form` will get an `:invalid` pseudo-class in CSS without any JS required. Might do the trick ;)

Comment: (you cannot have a `form` element between a `tr` and its cells in HTML, but you can use the HTML5 `form` attribute on the inputs to attach them to a form that is not their ancestor)

Comment: and by the way, you must not put the same `id` attribute on more than one element in a document, and IDs should not start with a digit

Answer (score 0):

Just elaborating on my comments about exploiting the browser's native form validation to write less code.

Pure CSS and HTML solution:

```
<style>
  #form1:invalid ~ table #row1 {
    background-color: red;
  }
  #form2:invalid ~ table #row2 {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<form id="form1"></form>
<form id="form2"></form>
<table class="table table-striped table-borderless" id="survey">
    <thead class="text-center">
      <!--...-->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="row1">
        <td scope="row">Question 1</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="f1" value="1" required form="form1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="f1" value="2" form="form1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="f1" value="3" form="form1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="f1" value="4" form="form1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="f1" value="5" form="form1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row2">
        <td scope="row">Question 2</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="f2" value="1" required form="form2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="f2" value="2" form="form2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="f2" value="3" form="form2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="f2" value="4" form="form2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="f2" value="5" form="form2"></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And if you really need JavaScript to know what's going on, you can call this to determine if a radio group has a value:

```
document.getElementById('form1').checkValidity()
```

It will return `false` if no radio in the group is selected.